# Synology : How to force reconnection of remote folder

Tags: mount, nas, cifs, synology-diskstation

I've a remote folder in the synology mount list that I need to manually reconnect every day to have access to it, otherwise it's not accesible.. (so go to File Station > tools > mount list ; and then right click on the remote folder and click on reconnect ).

Is there a command line to reconnect it without going to the admin GUI ? I use this remote folder in a Scheduled task ( basically I do a rsync to backup the NAS on this remote folder ) thus I could add this "reconnection" command at the beginning of Scheduled task.

Thank you

Comment: You should be able to add permanent mapping by : `NET USE S: "\\NAS_NAME\SHARE_NAME" /PERSISTENT:YES`.

Comment: I tried your command but I got an error : `NET: command not found`

Comment: Where are you entering the command?

Comment: on the NAS terminal